# Can constraintsWithVisualFormat be used with an unknown number of views?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Assuming I have an array of UIViews that are created dynamically and I'd add them to the same parent view, can I use constraintsWithVisualFormat to set set constraints so that they are vertically stacked? The ascii art required in constraintsWithVisualFormat doesn't seem to allow that.

If not, what's the best practice to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very simple:

```
UIView *view1 = [UIView new];
[view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIView *view2 = [UIView new];
[view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIView *view3 = [UIView new];
[view3 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

UIView *view4 = [UIView new];
[view4 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIView *view5 = [UIView new];
[view5 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[view5 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

NSArray *arrayOfViews = @[view1, view2, view3, view4, view5];

UIView *superview = self.view; //I tested in ViewController
[arrayOfViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *currentView, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [superview addSubview:currentView];
    [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                        views:@{@"view" : currentView}]];
    if (idx == 0)//If First element
    {
        [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]" options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"view" : currentView}]];
    }
    else if (idx != [arrayOfViews count] - 1)
    { //Not last element
        UIView *brotherView = arrayOfViews[idx - 1];
        [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[brotherView][currentView(brotherView)]" options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"brotherView" : brotherView, @"currentView" : currentView}]];
    }
    else //Last element
    {
        UIView *brotherView = arrayOfViews[idx - 1];
        [superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[brotherView][currentView(brotherView)]|" options:0 metrics:nil
                                                                            views:@{@"brotherView" : brotherView, @"currentView" : currentView}]];
    }
}];
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks. I actually did something very similar but instead of indexing the array, I created a pointer to the most recent view so that I could add a constraint off of that one.